# Difference between running a command through a remote module and Invoke-Command in powershell

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, powershell

I am in the process of trying to clean up some scripts we have and ran into an interesting issue.  If I use the following to load a remote module (in this case ActiveDirectory):

```
$cred= Get-Credential
$session= New-PSSession -ComputerName dc1 -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Import-Module ActiveDirectory} -Session $session
Import-PSSession -Session $session -module ActiveDirectory -Prefix Rem
```

Creating a new user account using  `New-RemADUser -samaccountname $samname -etc` everything works as expected.

However if I try to put it into a function, while there are no errors, no new account is created.

Example:

```
function newuser{
param([string]$givenname,[string]$surname,$etc)
New-RemADUser -GivenName $givenname -SurName...
}
$gname= Read-Host "Given name"
...
newuser($gname,$sname,$samname)
```

So my question is can the function not view the New-RemADUser cmdlet despite it running in the same script scope? Would I have to use Invoke-Command -Session $session New-ADUser... in order for the function to work?  Or is there some best practice or obvious reason my initial way to try it wouldn't work (values don't pass correctly, remote command doesn't 'exist' within the function, etc..)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a PowerShell function, the parameters are not comma-separated like in C#. When you call your function like this:

```
newuser($a,$b,$c)
```

the parser treats `($a,$b,$c)` as one single parameter, and since `newuser` expects the first argument to be a string, the parser tries to convert it to a single string - it's the equivalent of calling:

```
newuser -GivenName "$a $b $c"
```

Try calling it with a space separating the arguments instead, or, if you wanna be absolutely sure, give the parameter names explicitly:

```
newuser -GivenName $gname -Surname $surname -SamAccountName $etc
```

Comment: The spaces helped but having the parentheticals was what was keeping all the arguments seen as one string.  This is a rather confusing way to call a function and the built in about_Functions only explained the syntax for calling the function using the pipeline to supply or explicitly calling the switch to be used.  Still it put me on the right track to see what to look for so thank you.

Comment: @DavidV Glad I could help, sorry if it was poorly worded. You might also benefit from looking at the [`about_Parsing`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx) help file, explaining how the parser behavior differs when looking at arguments as opposed to expression

Comment: Will do thanks.  The wording wasn't poor more just me expecting the arguments to be wrapped in something, guess I'm just not as familiar with the syntax as I thought.

Comment: No shame in that, just keep on reading, coding and learning :-) Unless you're calling a native .NET method, parentheses usually only mean one thing in PowerShell: *evaluation precedence*